# Strategies for localizing large amounts of text in .NET applications

Tags: .net, asp.net, resources, localization

I'm working on an fairly large ASP application that will be fully localized. I'm using the standard named `resx` approach in satellite assemblies, with fallbacks (that is, `es-MX`, `es-CL` and fallback common to `es` and so on).

Not only will there be probably hundreds (if not a thousand or more!) of different strings; in some places the amount of text that needs to be stored as resource can be long, to the tune of a few paragraphs.

I'm guessing it will be a royal pain to manage these strings in the Visual Studio editor, not to mention the fact that the people who will do some of the translations won't have access to VS in the first place.

How do you folks that work on localized apps manage this type of thing? Any advice and pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: resx files are just xml and while some of the answers below are probably better suggestions, working with the raw XML would probably be preferable to the VS GUI. Some translation vendors are even quite good at translating content in xml while preserving schema.

Comment: @Jeff Even so, satellite assemblies require compilation and deployment for updates. So the XML editing would only be part of the strategy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you decide to go DB, check out this article: [Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization
Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/) by Rick Strahl and then [download it for free](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/695968.aspx)

If you decide to still using resx, you can use [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) to mitigate the pain.

Comment: Thank you, but using the database in this case is not practical, at least not for the vast majority of strings. Thanks for the link to the editor though, I'll try it out.

Comment: Resource Blender is another useful application to help manage resource files. Some useful features include importing and exporting to and from multiple formats and automatic translation via Google. http://www.resourceblender.com/

Answer (score 3):

I honestly don't know about the limitations of the resx files but, if there are some, you can do the following:

Create a table into the database which contains the translated texts. Then you would have to cache the loaded translated text when the website would be accessed.

Such approach would also help with the translation team, which doesn't have access to Visual Studio. The only problem I visualize is the creation of an extra WebApp which would allow the translation team to translate the texts. But still, it would be something simple.

In case you can't use the database for that, some XML files could do the job for you.

**EDIT:** I just found [another alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307466/localization-of-text-file-resources-in-net) but using .txt files. That can also help you.

Comment: I use Davis's approach for this problem.  I have a table with a column for each language (I name them with the standard language codes, es-MX, etc.) that I need and the rows are identified by where the translated piece of text belongs in the application, typically the control or field name.  It works great for the folks who have to do the translation, and I can just load up whichever language is needed at the moment from the database.  And I can switch languages on the fly just be grabbing a new column from the database.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and links. Like I said, using the database in this case isn't a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

If there is so much content it looks more like a problem that should be attacked/would be solved by a Content Management System.

Comment: This is a kind of vertical application, so a CMS wouldn't really help me.

Comment: I am just a bit worried about the amount of content. In my experience content will need updates and hardly ever the updates will be done by developers and need a very short time to market. Incorporating a CMS might be usefull to allow a content editor system.

Answer (score 1):

I started a project that had a small localization effort (4 languages, about a dozen pages) that grew into a much larger localization effort (9 languages, 40+ pages).

The resx file model is starting to be a huge PITA.  Adding the new files for a language is painful.  Adding the new files for a new page is painful.  Moving functionality between pages is painful.

A database-driven approach would probably be better, although I haven't tried it to be sure.

Edit: As for working with translators, I use Zeta Resource Editor to export/import the translation to/from a spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm four resx files into this and I can see how it's going to be a PITA indeed.

Answer (score 1):

use the free **Resource Translation Helper** tool ( http://www.winking.be/resource-translation-helper ).

1. backup your data
2. Add a location and select your project folder containing the .resx files
3. say where you want to store the .xls file *(this creates also another xml file containing the mappings, don't delete that file).*

give the Excel file to your translators, let them update the languages

1. after translating import the .xls file again to the folder

Works just fine!